# How to fix the JAVA Kafka Producer Error "Received invalid metadata error in produce request on partition" and Out of Memory when broker is down

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have been creating a Kafka Producer example using Java. I have been 
    sending normal data which is just "Test" + Integer as value to Kafka. I 
    have used the below properties and after I have started the Producer 
    Client and messages are on the way, during this I am killing the broker 
    and suddenly receiving the below error message instead of retrying.

Using 3 brokers and topic with 3 partitions and replication factor as 3 
and no min-insync-replicas

> **Below are the properties configured** config.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_IN_FLIGHT_REQUESTS_PER_CONNECTION, "1");
>   config.put(CommonClientConfigs.RETRIES_CONFIG, 60);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.ENABLE_IDEMPOTENCE_CONFIG, true);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.RETRY_BACKOFF_MS_CONFIG ,10000);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS_CONFIG ,30000);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_BLOCK_MS_CONFIG ,10000);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.MAX_REQUEST_SIZE_CONFIG , 1048576);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 0);
>   config.put(ProducerConfig.BUFFER_MEMORY_CONFIG, 1073741824); // 1GB

and the result when I have killed all my brokers or sometimes one of the 
        broker is as below

```
**Error:**
WARN org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer 
clientId=producer-1] Got error produce response with correlation id 124 
on topic-partition testing001-0, retrying (59 attempts left). Error: 
NETWORK_EXCEPTION
27791 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] WARN 
org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender  - [Producer 
clientId=producer-1] Received invalid metadata error in produce request 
on partition testing001-0 due to 
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.NetworkException: The server disconnected 
before a response was received.. Going to request metadata update now
28748 [kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1] ERROR 
org.apache.kafka.common.utils.KafkaThread  - Uncaught exception in thread 
'kafka-producer-network-thread | producer-1':
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at java.nio.HeapByteBuffer.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocate(Unknown Source)
at    org.apache.kafka.common.memory.MemoryPool$1.tryAllocate 
(MemoryPool.java:30)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.NetworkReceive.readFrom
(NetworkReceive.java:112)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.receive
(KafkaChannel.java:335)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.KafkaChannel.read
(KafkaChannel.java:296)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.attemptRead
(Selector.java:560)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.pollSelectionKeys
(Selector.java:496)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:425)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:510)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run
(Sender.java:239)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run
(Sender.java:163)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are testing the producer. When a producer connect to the Kafka cluster you will pass all broker IPs and ports as a comma separated string.  In your case  there are three brokers. When producer try to connect to cluster, as part of initialization cluster controller responds with cluster metadata. Assume your producer only populating message to a single topic. Cluster maintains a leader among brokers for each and every topic. After identify the leader for the topic, your producer only going to communicate to the leader until it is live.

In your testing scenario, you are deliberately killing the broker instances. When it happens kafka cluster need to identify a new leader for your topic and controller has to pass the new meta data to your producer. If the metadata change quite frequently( in your case you may kill another broker mean while) producer may receive invalid metadata.

Comment: Hi Steephen, Greeting and Thanks for the response. I have provided the 3 broker details in config and creating the Producer application in java only.  Problem is as I configured the retries it should retry until the new Leader have been elected, but instead its throwing an error and the Producer application is terminating. Main thing is it should retry for the number of retries and interval between retry. So , this ensures no data loss. Sorry, If I have not communicates well.

Comment: @pavankumar If all brokers are down, are you expecting producer have to retry?

Comment: Hi , Good Morning. Yes it is expected. Now I got some clue about the Out of Memory issue. I have changed my java 32 bit to 64 bit to have more Heap memory. After that dint observe any Out of Memory issues.

Comment: Happy to know that our discussion helped you!!